# table row as remote data link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My code looks like this at the moment:

**_index.html.erb**

```
<tr class="clickable" data-link=<%= edit_patient_report_path(@patient, report) %> data-remote="true"></tr>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#report-index').hide(); // #report-index => container with all reports
$('#report-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form') %>").show(); // #report-form => container for report form
```

**report.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'click','.clickable', (event) ->
    target = $(event.target)
    if target.is(':not(a)')
      if $(this).attr('data-link')
        window.location.href = $(this).data('link')
      else
        ...
```

**reports_controller.rb**

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js, :html
  ...
  def edit
  end
  ...
end
```

When I click on the table row it redirects to the edit form. But with no corresponding template available it throws a *Template is missing* error:

*Missing template reports/edit, application/edit with {:locale=>[:de], **:formats=>[:html]**}, ...*

**Can I make this row to a clickable remote-link?**

(Without implementing some kind of hidden link inside the row where it passes through)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @user3506853 help I solved my issue:

**report.js.coffee (updated)**

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'click','.clickable', (event) ->
    target = $(event.target)
    if target.is(':not(a)')
      if $(this).attr('data-link')
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'script',
          url: $(this).data('link')
        })
      else
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the tr to be clickable then you have to use js code, something like this:-

```
<tr data-href="<%= edit_patient_report_path(@patient, report) %>"></tr>

$(document).on('click', '#table-id tr', function() {
    var link = $(this).data('href');
     $.ajax({
         type: 'PUT',
         url: link
     });
});
```